# Debian: Card Reader device is available only for superuser

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, permissions, card-reader

I have an ASUS laptop with Realtek Card Reader RTL8411B.
I must install Debian with kernel version 4.15.3 - there is no any other option.

The first problem was in standard rtsx_pci driver which seems to ignore this card reader at all. Connecting SD card to laptop didn't cause appearance of any device in /dev directory or any new records in syslog and other logs too.

After reading some forums I understood that this problem in driver and there are two possible options to solve it:

1. Change kernel version with all kernel modules.
2. Build new driver for current kernel.

So I choose the second one and build custom driver form https://github.com/M0Rf30/rts_bpp.
Driver problem was solved. And now I get a new device /dev/sdb:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 may 13 13:47 /dev/sdb
```

But when the common user from disk group is trying to mount /dev/sdb to his own directory he recieves an error.

```
$ mount /dev/sdb /home/user/media
mount: /dev/sdb: Operation not permitted
```

I also created udev rule to set MODE="0666" for /dev/sdb device and now I have a device with permissions:

```
brw-rw-rw- 1 root disk 8, 16 may 13 13:53 /dev/sdb
```

But mount is still finishes with error. And not only mount.

```
$ mount /dev/sdb /home/user/media
mount: /dev/sdb: Operation not permitted
$ ls -l /dev/sdb
ls: can't get access to '/dev/sdb': Operation not permitted
```

Using this device with 'sudo' perfectly works but reading and writing data to/from SD card is available only for superuser.

So what I need to change to give access for all users to card reader device?

Answer (score 1):

The actual 'mount' system call is **only** available to root. The device node's permissions are irrelevant (and should be left as 0660, and you *really* shouldn't be putting unprivileged users in the 'disk' group).

There are several options for unprivileged access:

- Run the `mount` command via sudo, and specify the correct synthetic UID/GID/permissions through filesystem options – most cards hold the FAT filesystem, so you have to specify `uid=`.

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)
  ```
- Add an /etc/fstab entry for the SD card, with the 'user' option (relying on the fact that the 'mount' command is setuid):

  ```
  /dev/disk/by-path/usb-Foo-Bar-part1 /mnt auto user 0 0
  ```

  Using the symlinks from /dev/disk/by-path allows you to identify that specific card reader regardless of it being 'sdb' or 'sdc' today.
- Use the `pmount` wrapper to mount the card, which will enforce the correct options:

  ```
  pmount /dev/sdb
  ```
- Use the *UDisks* service to mount the card, which will always be mounted under `/run/media/$USER` (though there is an udev property to make it use `/media` instead):

  ```
  udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb
  ```

  With UDisks, the card will always be mounted under `/run/media/$USER` (though there is an udev property to make it use `/media` instead). This is the same mechanism that's used by GNOME, KDE and Xfce to allow unprivileged USB stick access.

Comment: I have already try to add /etc/fstab entry. Result is the same - operation not permitted.

Comment: I also tried to mount like this "sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g)". But after that mount point looks like this "d????????? ? ? ? ? ? media" with ls command. When I try to enter directory by cd I get "operation not permitted" error.

Comment: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb` - the same result, device is mounted but it's impossible to enter directory. And I don't have pmount in my OS and local repository, but I thinks it will not help as other options.

Comment: And I don't have any problems with usb devices. I can add user to floppy group or add /etc/fstab entry and user can mount and use usb device.